# TCL, How to name a variable that includes another variable

Tags: variables, tcl

In TCL, I'm writing a procedure that returns the depth of a clock.
But since I have several clocks I want to name the var: depth_$clk

```
proc find_depth {} {    
    foreach clk $clocks {    
        …    
        set depth_$clk $max_depth    
        echo $depth_$clk    
    }    
}
```

But I get:

```
Error: can't read "depth_": no such variable
        Use error_info for more info. (CMD-013)
```

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is this line:

```
    echo $depth_$clk
```

The issue is that the syntax for `$` only parses a limited set of characters afterwards for being part of the variable name; the `$` is not part of that. Instead, you can use the `set` command with *one* argument; `$` is effectively syntactic sugar for that, but the command lets you use complex substitutions.

```
    echo [set depth_$clk]
```

## **HOWEVER!**

The *real* correct thing to do here is to switch to using an associative array. It's a bit larger change to your code, but lets you do more as you've got proper access to substitutions in array element names:

```
proc find_depth {} {
    foreach clk $clocks {
        …
        set depth($clk) $max_depth
        echo $depth($clk)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!!! its working. Do you know how to make this associative array global? Meaning, I set it inside another proc and instead of returning its value I just want it to be global.

Comment: You can use the command 'global depth' before you reference depth in the procedure. Usually this is declared at the top of a proc. But you can also pass in an array by reference, which can be safer than using global variables. See the upvar command for passing variables by reference.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo ${depth}_$cell
```

This can help too.
Thanks !