# TCL : How can I check info for an array if array name is a variable too

Tags: tcl

I am not able to check if my array exists, the array name is in a variable. In my case array name contains space too.

```
code snippet:  
array set a\ b{  
    key1 "val1"  
}  

proc checkArr {name}
{
    if {![info exists $name($key)]} {  
       return {}  
    }
}

checkArr "a b"
```

error : *can't read "name(key1)": variable isn't array*

Can anyone help?

Comment: The sample you provided has a number of issues besides the problem you are stating. Please provide a reproducible code snippet.

Comment: Thank you @Jerry for reaching out. I just need help in the info exists if array name is a variable and has space. Kindly help

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44605149/tcl-how-to-name-a-variable-that-includes-another-variable?rq=1  et. al.

Answer (score 2):

The main issue with your code is that you are trying to see if an array exists in a local scope while it exists in a global scope.

```
array set a\ b {
  key1 "val1"
}

proc checkArr {name} {
  upvar $name arr
  if {![info exists arr(key1)]} {
    return 0
  } else {
    return 1
  }
}
```

In order to have the array accessible in the local scope of the proc, you can use either `global $name` or `upvar $name arr` (I used the latter above), or you can use `uplevel` when executing the `info exist` part.

Some other adjustments I carried out to the code:

- Added space to the `array set` part, otherwise you are supplying only one parameter to the function
- Changed `$name($key)` to `arr(key1)`. `info exists` takes a variable name, so if you use `$name($key)`, it will try to find the variable name for the value of that variable (if the value of `$name($key)` was 'value', `info exists` will try to find out if the variable named `value` exists, but the array value `$name($key)` doesn't exist, so you get the error).

Comment: The `if ... return ... else return ...` might be more readably: `return [info exists arr(key1)]`

Comment: Yes, I was keeping it in the `if ... else ...` format in the likely case OP would later use that structure to return something different. From the looks of it, they removed a significant part of the original code they have to show something suitable for the Q format, but introduced errors in the process.

Answer (score 0):

Let's create a command to check for the existence of a global array:

```
proc checkArr name {
    uplevel #0 [list info exists $name]
}

% checkArr "a b"
0
```

This command, when given `"a b"` as an argument executes the script `info exists {a b}`, but not at the local level inside the command: the `uplevel #0` part means that the script is executed at the global level.

Now we create the array, and check it:

```
% array set a\ b {key1 val1}
% checkArr "a b"
1
```

It exists. We can also check the existence of a member of the array using the same code:

```
% checkArr "a b(key1)"
1
```

In fact, any kind of string can be passed to `checkArr` and it will tell you if there is a variable (array or otherwise) with that name. If you want a specialized checker for array members, it can be written like this:

```
proc checkArrayMember {arrName memberName} {
    uplevel #0 [list info exists $arrName\($memberName)]
}

% checkArrayMember "a b" key1
1
```

The backslash in front of the left parenthesis takes away its syntactic meaning and makes it just a part of the string: the script essentially becomes `info exists {a b(key1)}`.

Documentation:
[array](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/array.htm),
[info](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/info.htm),
[list](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/list.htm),
[proc](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/proc.htm),
[uplevel](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/uplevel.htm),
[Summary of Tcl language syntax](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/Tcl.htm)