# Print the content of a dynamic array in tcl

Tags: arrays, tcl

I am trying to create n number of arrays from a file. The arrays are getting created properly when I try to print value of an array specifically by `$array_name(PAD)`, I am getting proper expected values. Now the issue is when I try to print the same value using a variable I am not getting the value.

Eg:

```
set f "BC1201_MP_PM"
puts  ${f}(PAD)
```

The output should be the content of `BC1201_MP_PM(PAD)`, but the output is "`BC1201_MP_PM(PAD)`". Can anyone please help.

Thanks in Advance!
Utkarsh

Comment: Try `[lsort [array names f]]`

Comment: `puts [set ${f}(PAD)]` There's probably a good duplicate but I don't have time to find one right now...

Comment: Oh, or you could use a single dict instead of a bunch of array variables: `dict set mydata BC1201_MP_PM PUB foo; puts [dict get $mydata $f PUB]`

Comment: I think we may have answered related questions before, such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44605149/tcl-how-to-name-a-variable-that-includes-another-variable/44605389#44605389) one.

Comment: Thanks shawn it works.

Comment: Thanks Donal for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways you can do this, some being better at some situations.

Without any context, I'd say the simplest would be to use `set` or a dictionary as Shawn suggested in the comments:

```
puts [set ${f}(PAD)]

# OR
dict set mydata BC1201_MP_PM PUB foo
puts [dict get $mydata $f PUB]
```

If it was a situation where you need to print all the array's contents, then you might as well use a loop with `array get`:

```
foreach {k v} [array get $f] {
    puts "The value for $k is $v"
}
```

In a `proc`, you may use `upvar` and pass the array name to the `proc` like so:

```
proc foo {arrayName} {
    upvar $arrayName localArray
    puts $localArray(PAD)
}
```

References: [`set`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm), [`array get`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/array.htm#M8), [`upvar`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/upvar.htm)